# Markdown sharp wrapping my html string in a "p" element?

Tags: c#, markdown, markdownsharp

I am using Markdownsharp v1.13.

The following statement:

```
new Markdown().Transform("<section id=\"archives\">\r\n        <p>\r\n            No archives.\r\n        </p>\r\n</section>")
```

Is wrapping the result into a p element:

```
> "<p><section id=\"archives\">\n        <p>\n            No archives.\n
> </p>\n</section></p>\n"
```

Why on earth is it doing that? I thought it should completely ignore, the html tags?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of block-level elements that prevent Markdown expansions inside them is hardcoded; see [line 590](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/browse/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs#590) and following.

This list does not include `<section>` elements by default (when Markdown was created, HTML5 was distant future), but as you can see, you can easily add other HTML tags to that list.